# How to access the same object from another class [JAVA]

Tags: java, object, global

I am managing a GUI and i was wondering if is there any way to manage the GUI instanced in one class, from another class. I explain better:
One class create the GUI Object, is there any way to modify the same GUI istance from another class?
Even if i create the object as public, i can't access it without receive the error "cannot make a static reference to the non-static field"
I am stuck with this problem since in java there is no C-Style Global vars...
If it is not possible, how can i create a smartly managing GUI system?
If i create the GUI in one class, how can i be able to modify it later, due to what happen in others classes?

Comment: Pass a `reference` of the object to the instance of the other class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use a Singleton class for GUI.

```
public class GUI {
private static GUI ourInstance = new GUI();

public static GUI getInstance() {
    return ourInstance;
}

private GUI() {
    //private constructor
}
public void method() {}
}
```

then you can use everywhere.
A Singleton class means, that only one object will be in your memory.

```
GUI.getInstance().method();
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you can do. e.g -

1. Pass the `reference` of class1 to the instance of class2.
2. `Singleton` object you can create which will be always same throughout your application.

Comment: can you explain better the first solution? Singleton solved my problem... but i want to understand first solution too

Comment: "Singleton solved my problem", sounds good but you didn't upvote :).

To understand 1st solution, you need understand is-a and has-a relationship first. Please find this link that may give you some idea. 
https://www.javatpoint.com/aggregation-in-java